# Pass data from viewcontroller tableview to another view controller

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, tableview

I am having an issue with passing data to another view controller from a table view controller. I'm trying to pass the names of the users to another view controller. So far, the core data is working by storing the names of the users and deleting the names of the people in the cells, but when I select a user from the list, it does not take me to the next view controller.

```
class tableViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

//Properties
var people: [NSManagedObject] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "The List"
    tableview.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
//Fetching data from the core data
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    //1. Before requesting to coredata, it needs a managed object context.
    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }

    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    //2. Using NSFetchRequest class to fetch core data. Fetching all obejcts within an entity (Person).
    let fetchRequest =
        NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Person")

    //3. Putting in the fetch request to the managed object context, to get fetch data.
    do {
        people = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
//Adding the person's name into the table view when the clicks on the add button and enter in their name.
@IBAction func addName(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Name",
                                  message: "Add a new name",
                                  preferredStyle: .alert)

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) {
        [unowned self] action in

        guard let textField = alert.textFields?.first,
            let nameToSave = textField.text else {
                return
        }

        self.save(name: nameToSave)
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
                                     style: .default)

    alert.addTextField()

    alert.addAction(saveAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    present(alert, animated: true)
}

// Where the coredata is stored.
func save(name: String) {

guard let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
}

//1.Before saving or retrieving from core data, NSManagedObjectContext is to be implemented. Managed context is considered s in-memory to working with managed object context.
let managedContext =
    appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

//2. Creating new managed object and inserting it into managed object context. NSEntityDescrption links he entity definitionfrom data model with an instance of NSanagedObject at runtime.
let entity =
    NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Person",
                               in: managedContext)!

let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                             insertInto: managedContext)

//3. The "name" attribute is set using the key value coding. KVC key (name) should be spelt as diplayed in data model else app could crash at run time.
person.setValue(name, forKeyPath: "name")

//4. Changed are saved to the disk using the managed object context. Save could bring an error which is why try is used within do and catch block. The new managed object is inserted into the "people" array, so it appears when table view is reloaded.
do {
    try managedContext.save()
    people.append(person)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
}
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
extension tableViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return people.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    -> UITableViewCell {

        let person = people[indexPath.row]
        let cell =
            tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell",
                                          for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text =
            person.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String
        return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        //print("Deleted")

        //short-cut to access App Delegate
        let ad = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = ad.persistentContainer.viewContext
        ad.saveContext()

        context.delete(people[indexPath.row])
        people.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little    preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

}
```

}

Comment: Where is the relevant code part?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to pass the person selected to the next ViewController after selecting them from your tableview?

First declare a class variable for the person your selecting.

```
var selectedPerson: NSManagedObject?
```

Then you need to implement the function

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedPerson = people[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPerson", sender: nil)
}
```

After that, edit your current function to this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showPerson" {
        if let personController = segue.destination as? YOURPERSONCONTROLLERCLASS {
            personController.person = selectedPerson
        }
    }
}
```

You'll have to change YOURPERSONCONTROLLERCLASS to the viewcontroller class and that class will also need a variable person of type NSManagedObject.

Comment: If its what your looking for, click the tick icon on the left of my answer to accept it. Thanks